# Is there a better way to iterate over nested loops in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, optimization

I have some code that is running through nested loops. I am guessing that there is a more "pythonic" way of doing this. Any suggestions?

The basic section of code looks like this:

```
   for e in range(len(listOfTuples)):

        for item in self.items:
            if item.getName() == listOfTuples[e][0]:
                <do stuff>
            if item.getName() == listOfTyples[e][1]:
                <do other stuff>
                continue

        if <both above if statements got answers>:
            <do yet more stuff>
```

Is there a better way to write these nested loops?

Comment: you could use `elif` instead of `if`

Comment: @Jean The `if`s aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need the index, so you could do `for tuple in listOfTuples:` There's nothing un-pythonic about (shallow) nested loops though.

Comment: Is the last `if` supposed to be inside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function. At least it hides the "ugliness" of a nested for loop to you.

```
def combine_items_and_tuples(items, listOfTuples):
   for e in range(len(listOfTuples)):
        for item in items:
            yield e, item
```

simply call it with:

```
for e, item in combine_items_and_tuples(self.items, listOfTuples):
      if item.getName() == listOfTuples[e][0]:
                <do stuff>
      if item.getName() == listOfTyples[e][1]:
                <do other stuff>
                continue

      if <both above if statements got answers>:
            <do yet more stuff>
```

As already mentioned in the comments, you can also iterate of the `listOfTuples` directly, since it is iterable (have a look in the python [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html)):

```
for tuple in listOfTuples:
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate directly over the `listOfTuples` and unpack the values we care about

```
for a, b, *_ in listOfTuples:

    a_check, b_check = False, False

    for item in self.items:
        if item.name == a:
            #do stuff
            a_check = True         
        if item.name == b:
            #do stuff
            b_check = True

    if a_check and b_check:
        #do more stuff
```

The `*_` captures stuff past the first two elements of the tuples in `listOfTuples` (Assuming all we want is the first two elements).

Notice I use `item.name` instead of `item.getName`.  Python generally doesn't care about getters and setters because there's no real concept of a private variable.